# Flask Application (MySQL) - KeyError: 'migrate'

Tags: mysql, flask

In order to perform a `migration`, through commands `flask db init` and `flask db migrate`, I receive the following error: `directory = current_app.extensions['migrate'].directory KeyError: 'migrate'`.

I have created a `Migrate` object within my `__init__.py` file, however, still receive the error stated above:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

from config import app_config
from flask_login import LoginManager

from flask_migrate import Migrate

# Creating Flask app.
app = Flask(__name__)

# Database variable initialisation.
db = SQLAlchemy()

login_manager = LoginManager()

def create_app(config_name):
    app = Flask(__name__, instance_relative_config=True)
    app.config.from_object(app_config[config_name])
    app.config.from_pyfile('config.py')
    db.init_app(app)

    # Creating login manager object and initialising it.
    # Login view and message prevent a user to accessing a page they are not authorised to.
    login_manager.init_app(app)
    login_manager.login_message = "Please login to access this page."
    login_manager.login_view = "auth.login"

    migrate = Migrate(app, db)
    from app import models

    return app
```

Any advice for what I am doing wrong? I have already viewed quite a few pages related to this error and have implemented the possible alterations.

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem. The above `__init__.py` class was completely fine.

My `config.py` file which contained the following code:

```
SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = 'mysql+mysqlconnector://{db_user}:{my_password}@localhost/{database}'
```

... had a `format` extension to it which was not needed. I have successfully updated my database.